# React State with array

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

Currently I'm trying to run a function that pulls an array of keys from an endpoint. Every time this function is called I want the array on my state to be cleared or reset but it keeps appending to the original. So this.state.keys array just keeps growing larger with every request. I'm brand new to React so please go easy on me.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './app.css';
import ReactImage from './react.png';
// import Networks from './Networks/Networks.js';
import Networks from './Networks/Networks.js';
import Button from './Button/Button.js';
import axios from 'axios'

export default class App extends Component {
  state = { 
  networks: [],
  selectedNetwork: "",
  keys: [],
};

getKeys = (networkId) => {
  console.log(this.state)
  fetch('/api/getKeys', {method:'get', headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(keys => this.setState({
    keys: keys
  }));
}

toggleNetwork = () => {
  this.setState({selectedNetwork: document.querySelector('#funtime').value})
}
componentDidMount() {
  let networkList = [];
  fetch('/api/getNetworks')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(networks => this.setState({
      networks: networks.rval
  }));
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {<Networks  toggleNetwork={() => this.toggleNetwork()}
                  networks={this.state.networks}/>}
      <Button state={this.state}
              value={this.state.selectedNetwork}
              clickAction={() => this.getKeys(this.state.selectedNetwork)}
              name="Get Keys"/>
      <img src={ReactImage} alt="react" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In your getKeys() do this.setState({keys: []}) on the first line of the function before you make the call to get the new set of keys.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the backend...reseting the setState to a blank array made me realize this but you shouldn't need to do that. setState should overwrite.